# Async jest assertions not failing test, but assertion error prints in test output

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a provider object that returns a promise. I am trying to create jest unit tests for this provider object.

Here is an example test:

```
  it('Should return repos for a known account', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(apiProvider.ReposForUser('joon').then((data) => data.length)).resolves.toBeGreaterThan(0).then(done());
  });
```

I am just resolving the promise with a blank array for now in the provider class (i.e. I expect the test to fail):

```
export class GithubAPIProvider implements IGithubDataProvider {
  public ReposForUser(githubUser: string): Promise<GithubRepoData[]> {
    return new Promise<GithubRepoData[]>((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve([]);    
    });
  }  
}
```

When I run my jest script, i see a failed promise error in the output text, but the test shows as having passed:
[image]

I have used a done callback in my test, why is jest not waiting for the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem is. I was calling the done function in my then method instead of passing a reference to the done method.

Code now looks like this: ["done" instead of "done()"]:

```
it('Should return repos for a known account', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(apiProvider.ReposForUser('joon').then((data) => data.length)).resolves.toBeGreaterThan(0).then(done);
  });
```